# How to properly refactor a Java method for proper error handling

Tags: java, error-handling, exception

I have an existing Java method that I am not sure how to refactor properly. I want the `finally` clause to always be called, however some callers need to know when an exception is thrown so they can do some additional housekeeping.

Should the method remain as it is below, or do I remove all `catch` clauses and throw them instead? Is there another way to handle this?

UPDATE: Sorry, forgot to mention, I have to use Java version 6

I would think a finally clause is somewhat unorthodox without accompanying catches but not sure of the right way to go about this.

```
public static final synchronized String getContents(File file) {
    StringBuilder builder = null;       
    Reader reader = null;
    try {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
        int data;
        while((data = reader.read()) != -1) {
            builder.append((char)data);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IO Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);           
    }
    finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IO Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);           
        }           
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: What issue you getting here. I am not able to understand what is issue here.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: maybe a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Google for "try with resources". And there's nothing wrong with a finally with no catches.

Comment: @Janny I am trying to refactor the method but not sure of the proper way to go about it

Comment: It is an interesting question. It depends about your logic. I also think it as to do with the check/uncheck exception use. If you want the caller to be able to manage properly a problem, you can try to define your own checked exception instead of unchecked ones (RuntimeException are unchecked). This way, the checked exception is part of the method signature and the caller knows he may happen and has the possibility to catch it and process it.

Comment: @JordiCastilla JFPicard this question is not off topic for Stack Overflow, so it should not be migrated. Also, questions for Code Review should have *complete, working code* and a desire for all aspects of the code to be reviewed, not individual questions. Please see [**A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users**](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @durron597 that was not my intention, I didn't said is offtopic, either voted to close... I simply give a clue to OP to have better answers to rewied the code... codereview users are wizards with this kind of questions...

Comment: @JordiCastilla I understand that, I am just trying to provide more specific guidance about what sorts of questions are for Stack Overflow and which are for Code Review; not just for you but for everyone who reads this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* a `catch` block to use `try` ... `finally`. Nested exceptions are harder to read, so I'd leave them out.

Comment: Additionally, you should always use try with resources (as pointed out in the other answers) if you can. Edit: nvm, Java 6. It's still true for all other versions though.

Comment: I am leaning towards this answer ... so simply throw all exceptions but keep the finally block? For me, this is the best option unless there is a good reason NOT to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 7, you can use the [try-with-resources-Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
public static final synchronized String getContents(final File file) {
    StringBuilder builder = null;
    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream (file))) {
        int data;
        while ( (data = reader.read ()) != -1) {
            builder.append ((char) data);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException ("IO Exception: " + e.getMessage (), e);
    }
    return builder.toString ();
}
```

That way, your reader is always closed and there is no need, in this instance, for a `finally` block.

---

That is because `Reader` implements [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). If you have the following code:

```
try (AutoCloseable ac = /*create object here*/ {
//bla bla, do something with ac
}
```

The JVM **guarantees** that close() is invoked on ac!*

*Unless, of course, the JVM is killed itself.

Comment: finally block is required here. reader is close in side that. it's not good idea to remove this block.

Comment: we need the finally block

Comment: Please take a look at [try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html); the finally block is not required with this statement. Instead, using try (Reader r = new Reader()... assures that r is *always closed*. Reader implements `AutoCloseable`, and therefore after that kind of try block reader.close() is **always** invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final synchronized String getContents(File file) {
    StringBuilder builder = null;       
    Reader reader = null;
    try {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
        int data;
        while((data = reader.read()) != -1) {
            builder.append((char)data);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
            reader.close();         
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Not much I would change

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` section is always executed regardless the code inside `try` will be executed properly or an exception will be thrown. So you can remove `catch` block but have to remember to add `IOException` into method signature (because it is checked).

Also, if you use Java 7 you could use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).